# Is token a Rails core method ? - Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to generate a unique token, using this tutorial: http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/6434

But I get this error message when I try:

```
undefined method `token=' for #<Stage:0x00000102a13aa8>
```

This is what my Stage model looks like:

```
# == Schema Information
# Schema version: 20110131093541
#
# Table name: stages
#
#  id         :integer         not null, primary key
#  project_id :integer
#  user_id    :integer
#  name       :string(255)
#  stage_num  :integer
#  created_at :datetime
#  updated_at :datetime
#


class Stage < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :project
  #has_and_belongs_to_many :users

  has_many :uploads, :dependent => :destroy, :order => 'created_at DESC'
  has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy

    #this is where the token is generated for the client
    def generate_client_token(length=25)
    alphanumerics = ('a'..'z').to_a.concat(('A'..'Z').to_a.concat(('0'..'9').to_a))
    self.token = alphanumerics.sort_by{rand}.to_s[0..length]

        #Ensure uniqueness of the token..
        generate_client_token unless Stage.find_by_token(self.token).nil?       
    end 

end
```

In my view, I am calling that method like this:

```
<%= @stage.generate_client_token %>
```

Thoughts ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't defined the `token` field in your `stages` table. You can do this by generating a migration that has this:

```
add_column :stages, :token, :string
```

Or by simply running a migration that already has this (if there is one)